# Vue: beforeEach is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

Route change doesn't scroll to top, so Vue creator [advises](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/173#issuecomment-149073396) to use navigation guards. In [the updated version](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/173#issuecomment-269746851):

```
Router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  next();
})
```

Perfect, except it yields this fatal error in my app: ncaught TypeError: vue_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.beforeEach is not a function

Why?

Just in case here's my complete router.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import PastEvents from './views/PastEvents.vue'
import BasicPage from './views/BasicPage.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/past-events',
      name: 'past-events',
      component: PastEvents
    },
    {
      path: '/basic-page',
      name: 'basic-page',
      component: BasicPage
    }
  ]
})

Router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  next();
})
```

Answer (score 9):

You've capitalized `Router`, that's the class name. What you want to do is add your `.beforeEach()` to the instance of the router. You'll notice in the documentation that it's always a lowercase `router` they're adding the guards to.

Currently, you're immediately exporting the instance from the module, so you'll need to first add it to a variable when you create a `new Router` and then add your `.beforeEach()` clauses to it before finally exporting it.

```
const router = new Router({
  ...
})

router.beforeEach( ... )

export default router
```